# Flutter scrollable list inside overlay

Tags: flutter, overlay, scrollable

My question is similar to this [How to make my page scrollable when i show overlay element, that have too many items in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463711/how-to-make-my-page-scrollable-when-i-show-overlay-element-that-have-too-many-i) but it has no answers so I'll try to ask as well:

I have an Overlay showing a list of questions using ListView. The list of questions is long and I need to enable scrolling **inside** the Overlay.

Now it's static and part of it disappears at the bottom of the mobile device.

Why is not just scrollable (since the list inside the Overlay is inside a ListView) and is there a way to make it scrollable?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE (SOLVED) :**

The problem was that the **ListView** widget is inside a **Positioned** widget and the **top**, **left**, **bottom** and **width** values (in my case) need to be set in order for the content to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the **ListView** widget is inside a **Positioned** widget and the **top**, **left**,**bottom** and **width** values (in my case) need to be set in order for the content to be scrollable.